# Print response from php scrip through ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to call a remote php script and that php script will echo any string and then I want to alert that string back to ajax. but when I am alerting that string, I am getting this

[image]

Following is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var response= $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   dataType:'text',
   url:"http://mySiteURL.com/evote.php?checkVote="+voterId+"&fingerPrint="+fingerPrint,
   async:true,
   success:function(result){alert(result);},
   error: function(result){alert(result);} 
 });
});
```

and following is my php script code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['checkVote'])){
$voterId=$_POST['checkVote'];
$fingerPrint=$_POST['fingerPrint'];



echo "Output from php";
}

?>
```

before this I searched many questions on stack overflow but problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the reponse into string : JSON.stringify(result)

```
 var response= $.ajax(
{
  type:"POST",
  dataType:'html', // <-----
  url:"http://mySiteURL.com/evote.php?checkVote="+voterId+"&fingerPrint="+fingerPrint ,
  // async:true, // <--- no need 
  success:function(result){alert(JSON.stringify(result));}, 
  error: function(result){alert(JSON.stringify(result));} })
```

For the PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['checkVote'])){
    $voterId=$_GET['checkVote'];
    $fingerPrint=$_GET['fingerPrint'];
    echo "Output from php";
} else {
    echo "No POST";
}
?>
```

Comment: As the request isn't json, why should the return value be json?

Comment: inspecting result could help. So JSON.stringify is a way.

Comment: now I am getting following in alert: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: Seem success and error function have 3 parameters... Check documentation.

Comment: the problem still persists

Comment: check with $_GET['checkVote'] even you use post. I susect isset($_POST['checkVote']) is false.

Comment: also tried $_GET['checkVote']. Still getting same output: [object Object]

Comment: I had added else clause before(else {echo "end";}). still getting same output

Comment: One thing I would like to mention that from ajax I am able to change my mysql database but when I want to retrieve data I am unable to do so

Comment: ajax is able to access php for changing something but when I wan to retrieve some data it does not return except: [object Object]

Comment: if there is another way to get data from my sql through ajax. I would appreciate as it would do my task

Comment: You can try vanilla JS for AJAX. I have no other idea.

Comment: Is the html source you work with located in the server ?